# Post Image from android to WCF Rest service and Get response back as image

Tags: android, wcf, rest

I need to post an **Image** to **wcf service** and service will perform some operations on image and response back image. How to do that? I need help on both sides **android and wcf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that is easy as long as you are accepting and returning `Stream` and using `WebHttpBinding`.  See [Can a WCF REST endpoint be forced to accept Raw message format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011417/can-a-wcf-rest-endpoint-be-forced-to-accept-raw-message-format) and [How to: Create a Service That Returns Arbitrary Data Using The WCF Web HTTP Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221(v=vs.110).aspx)

Basically as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "processImage")]
public Stream ProcessImage(Stream inputImage)
{
    // do stuff with inputImage
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    return /* some stream with jpeg data */;
}
```

From the client, you are just posting an HTTP request.  See [Sending images using Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post) but use the resultant `HttpResponse` to [access the returned image](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity()).